# SELECT min date for a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The date column of my table is VARCHAR not datetime.

Eg

```
entry
'03/01/2011'
'03/22/2011'
'05/22/2010'
```

when I do a

```
SELECT min(entry) FROM table
```

I will get '03/01/2011' as it is the min in alphabetical order.  I want to retrieve '05/22/2010' instead which is the min date.  How do I convert the column to datetime and get the min.

Thanks

Comment: Notwithstanding the answers given, which will work - this is why you dont store dates in a varchar column!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming all entries are 'castable' as `datetime`:

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(entry as datetime))
FROM table
```

---

Assuming there might be some cases where `entry` isnt a `datetime`:

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(ISDATE([entry]),0),'31/12/9999') as datetime))
FROM table
```

---

If all records are a date column, as @Steve Wellens recommended, I would change the datetype to a `datetime` field to save future problems

Answer (score 7):

I would fix your database schema.  Change the column type to a datetime.  Otherwise you'll have problems forever.

Comment: +1 Also, if you have SQL 2008 or higher, use date instead of datetime. Since your not storing time data, you'll save 5 bytes per row on both logical and physical disk space.

Comment: -1 for not answering question as it may not be possible in the asker's environment

Comment: According to the tags, the environment is SQL Server.  Perhaps you meant the requirements don't allow it.  Fair enough.  However, the suggestion not only fixes the current problem but could potentially head off many more in the future.  Constructive suggestions are a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `varchar` a `date` (or `datetime`) by using [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CAST`ing it.

```
SELECT min(CAST(entry AS DATETIME)) FROM table
```

Hope this helps.